# How will updates be applied to the Nexus 7 Ubuntu release? Will refreshing the device be necessary?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Updating Android is usually a hassle and requires flashing an update via ROM Manager or the like.

I'm fantasizing about the beauty of being able to take daily Ubuntu patches and updated kernels via apt.  Is this a reality or does the platform require Ubuntu to repackage new ROMs/ go back through the desktop installer for every release?

Answer (score 2):

Updates will be pushed to a PPA, and a simple `apt-get dist-upgrade` will pull them down.  No reflashing necessary

Comment: Any specific (additional) PPA's required?

Comment: No PPA's are required, but there is one included in the image for some nexus 7 specific bits (i.e. the kernel, our version of nux, etc) that you may want to keep there.  It's currently in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-nexus7-ppa.list if I recall correctly.

Comment: Is there any advantage in re-installing to **Nexus 7**, with an updated desktop 'Installer' (which has been updated recently)?

Comment: If you could ask that as a new question, I'd be glad to answer it so other people can find the same info :)

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215543/ubuntu-nexus-7-desktop-installer-what-do-the-updates-provide

Answer (score 2):

To Add to Chris Waynes answer

At this time it is necessary to include the Nexus 7 PPA (ppa:ubuntu-nexus7/ppa) for the hardware specific bits. Updates will continue to be pushed via apt. The long term goal is to include all these requirements into the main and universe ppa of Raring Ringtail (13.04)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is a reality, and a simple one too. It would all work through the update manager. These Ubuntu-Android builds would be treated how the various live Ubuntu version (11.04, 11.10, 12.04, 12.10), each having their own specific updates.

I assure you though that Ubuntu always strives for simplicity and ease of use, especially when it comes to installation and upgrades.

You can follow all the progress for Nexus 7 Ubuntu at [HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7) and [HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation#Troubleshooting_the_Install), all of your questions will be answered.

Please keep in mind the this type of question fits firmly into this statement listed on the FAQ:

"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: I feel as this question is fine as per the FAQ.

Comment: He was not asking a question based on an actual problem. As you can see in the answer provided by @Chris Wayne above, it was more for just chating about it, open discussion.