# What do the updates provide in the Nexus 7 Desktop Installer?

Tags: installation, updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is there any advantage in re-installing to Nexus 7, with an updated 'Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer' which has itself been updated recently?

*Presumably it has added support for 32GB model ..*

Does it give you any further updates than can **not** be achieved on the device itself?

eg. **by typing:** `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The newer version of the installer includes support for the 32gb model, as well as an updated info screen warning the user that this is a developer release.  It also has some fixes for incorrectly cached downloads.

Now vs updating and then re-installing, you can get essentially the same results by upgrading.  However, a simple upgrade won't do, you'll need to run (on the device):
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-image-nexus7`

The reason for the additional package install is that there was a change in the kernel meta-package structure.  Doing this will essentially create a system that's the same as doing a fresh install with the new image.

It is a matter of preference at this point, as a fresh install is often preferred by some people to ensure a consistent experience, but an updated system should be comparable.

Comment: The only thing that you need to fix with a full re-install is the  possibly inappropriate hostname bug.

Comment: Any issue with renaming hostname? - with permissions, keyring, etc.

Comment: I don't think so, david, but I am not 100% sure.  We set it by changing the /etc/hostname file and by running hostname <newhostname>.  Rebooting after would be cleanest.