# Fastboot gets stuck while sending userdata image (raring preinstalled) to nexus 7

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, 13.04

I am trying to install the latest pre-installed image of Ubuntu on my Nexus 7. However, I am stuck at flashing the userdata image. I have all my drivers and Android SDK updated.

Having said that, this seems like a image size issue. I read elsewhere on the Internet ([here actually](http://ruedigergad.com/2012/12/09/nexus-7-easily-flashaccess-entire-userdata-partition/)), that there is a size limitation on flashing 'userdata' partition; which is max 700MB.

This is interesting, because the size of `raring-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+nexus7.img` shows up as 690MB, however, when flashing it, fastboot quotes it as 705701 KB.

I suspect that this could be a problem, because the previous version 12.xx was less than 700000 KB and hence I was able to easily flash it.

Any help is appreciated on how to flash this new version, or whether I should flash the old version and upgrade it.

Some info on the devices:
Nexus 7 16GB
Host OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1

**UPDATE**: Initially I was following the [Manual Install instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation#Manually_Installing_Ubuntu_13.04_on_Nexus_7) from Ubuntu Nexus 7 Wiki. While flashing gunzipped image `raring-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+nexus7.img`, fastboot showed the size as `705701 KB` and consistently went to disk sleep.

However, today I tried the installer script (`ubuntu-nexus7-installer`) and the fastboot flash was successful. This time fastboot showed the size as `692481KB`

I am going to file this as a bug instead and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'current' Raring / 13.04 image does install on the Nexus 7, and updating (with appropriate commands) brings this up to latest versions.

from: [What do the updates provide in the Nexus 7 Desktop Installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215543/what-do-the-updates-provide-in-the-nexus-7-desktop-installer)

> .. Now vs updating and then re-installing, you can get essentially the same results by upgrading. However, a simple upgrade won't do, you'll need to run (on the device):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-image-nexus7
> ```

---

If you are trying to do something '*more clever*' than that, it is probably outside the scope of this forum to assist you.

- **Why are you trying this method?**
- **Have you asked the author (of the post you noted) for assistance?**

Comment: I was following the Manual Install instructions on the Ubuntu Nexus 7 Wiki page itself. The reasons for doing this are:
a. The ubuntu-nexus-installer package also install fastboot, which I already have and hence a little conflict.

Comment: b. I regularly flash my own custom images to the device manually.
 
 
Anyway, that post I referred to was what I found when I was searching for a solution regarding why fastboot goes to disk sleep when trying to flash the image to userdata. The author simply mentioned that there is such a limitation to size and installing MOSLO could help. Seems like a rather convoluted solution.

Anyway, as you have suggested, I will give the upgrading process a try, using 12.04 image and upgrading to 13.04.

Comment: Thanks for the tip mate. Even though I was able to get to the current version, it had graphics issues. The top menubar and unity bar where garbled. I reckon I should file that as a bug.  
Steps I followed: Manually flashed quantal image I had from previous install. `sudo apt-get update` and `dist-upgrade`d and then finally installed `linux-image-nexus7`. Then rebooted. All was fine except the graphics

Comment: **ERRATA** I meant Quantal 12.10 in the comments posted above.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a **new** install of Raring / **13.04** (*which I have already done*), either using tool or manual steps. The update commands should keep you up-to-date after that ..